# Visual Studio Auto-Formatting On Save Bug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I save an aspx file in Visual studio (2017), it auto indented html lines and put `</br>` tags on the first CTRL+S try instead of saving the file. Then I hit CTRL+Z to take this change back but it did the same again every time I tried. Every time it did it, VS changed almost half of the file (2k lines) so undoing was painfully slow as well. Tried disabling all the auto formatting settings that I was able to find online on SO and Microsoft forums, it didn't work. Tried restarting Visual studio, it didn't work.

Comment: This is solved. Restarting did the trick for me.